# Wordpress loads all stylesheets using http instead of https

Tags: javascript, wordpress, https, assets

I have the following problem:
Wordpress keeps loading nearly all assets using http instead of https.
The url in the settings says https, in the options table in database it says https and there is no entry in the entire database saying "http".
I also checked the wp-config file and there is nothing declared either...
[image: assets being loaded in the head]

I really do not know what else to check, has anyone any idea?

Comment: If you're website has all secure urls in the `settings` and you are using `hello-elementor` theme which uses properly enqueued stylesheets, my best bet would be that this is a caching issue. Try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the WP plugin "Better Search & Replace" https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/.
Use the plugin to look for "http://" and replace with "https://" in your wp database. This plugin preserves serialized data, but just in case always backup your db first before performing DB surgery!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but of course I did that. That’s why I said there is no http:// found in the database.

Comment: Check your .htaccess file for redirection rules